# Полезно ли давать ответы с кодом на C, когда просят сделать что-то более-менее универсальное на C-подобном языке?

Tags: обсуждение

С одной стороны, это бывают учебные задачи, и новичок не сможет переделать C-код на нужный язык. С другой стороны, поисковик может найти вопрос по его заголовку, и тому, кто может перекодировать с C на C-подобный язык, ответ в таком случае может быть полезен.

Comment: Хорошо бы увидеть несколько примеров. Ну и порой даже псевдокод бывает полезен. Так что в целом, я думаю, полезно, но вариант с родным языком вопроса будет ещё полезнее.

Comment: Это по мотивам сегодняшнего [динозаврика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/713736/213987) что ли вопрос?

Comment: Лучше описать алгоритм на [псевдокоде](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2)). Вот например ваш [недавний ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/713884/1365). Хотя js немного похож на Си (ага, фигурными скобочками), но не факт, что новичку, изучающему js, ваш ответ будет понятен и полезен.

Answer (score 4):

Как правило, код в ответе должен соответствовать языкам в метках вопроса. Если вы не считаете уместным изменить метки вопроса в выбранном случае,
 то не стоит код на другом языке публиковать.

Часто, даже простые задачи могут быть решены по разному в выбранном языке, используя различные идиомы. Если добавить сюда другие языки с похожим синтаксисом, но со своими особенностями, то вариантов ещё больше.

Если вы, как автора кода, имеете сложности перевести ваш код с Си на Си-подобный язык, то у читателей могут ещё бо́льшие сложности возникнуть.

Если вы думаете, что будущим посетителям код именно на Си больше подойдёт, то *можно "Как сделать X на Си" как отдельный вопрос опубликовать.* По желанию, оставить комментарий в Си-подобном вопросе с ссылкой на Си решение.

То есть, как правило, если просят код на JavaScript следует код на JavaScript писать, а код на Си в другом вопросе помещать.

Чего точно не следует делать, это копировать двадцать раз один и тот же ответ в похожие вопросы, которые отличаются только выбранными языками.

Конечно, не следует общие правила слепо применять. К примеру, если вопрос имеет метку [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc) и акцент не на особенностях языка и его идиом, а именно на используемом алгоритме, то есть если ваш алгоритм читаем именно в Си (Си выполняет роль исполняемого псевдо-кода), то как дополнение словесного описания алгоритма, как более точная его версия, может использоваться код на каком бы то ни было языке. В данном случае, Си является заменой русскому языку, а не к примеру JavaScript. Очевидно, лучше писать на заявленном в метках языке, если это не ухудшает понимание алгоритма.